# Switching between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a log in form on my app.  Once a correct user name and pass word are provided I want the log in form to close and my main form to open.  I had trouble doing this so I used a quick fix and coded it so that a succesful login meant the log in form's Visible property got set to false (making it look like it had closed to the user).  But I'm not happy with this solution since it means the log in form is always open.

The code I have on my frmLogIn is

```
Form fM = new frmMain();
this.Visible = false;
fM.Show();
```

How do I change this so that frmLogIn actually closes as frmMain opens?

PS. I also tried this code from another thread on these forums, but this doesnt work either.

```
Form fM = new frmMain();
fM.Location = this.Location;
fM.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
fM.FormClosing += delegate { this.Show(); };
fM.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: are you looking for the function `Close()`? That will close your form. (That would also call the FormClosing event for the form that is closing, in where you can show your other Form)

Comment: Have you tried this.Close() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say you are in the main applications forms Load event. Here you might launch your login screen

```
LoginForm logForm = new LoginForm();
logForm.ShowDialog();
```

Then you might get whether the login passed from the relevant `logForm`'s accessor, so in the `logForm`'s Closing event

```
this.passedLogin = true;
this.Close();
```

then back in the main forms Load event after the `ShowDialog()` above, you could check if the login passed, if it did not close the application or force a reattempt

```
if (!logForm.passedLogin)
    this.Close();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had not read the other answers and I see what you mean. Apologies. But I assure you this is the case of great minds think alike.

Comment: np ... that's why I put the smiley in there

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend do do it the other way:
In your MainForms - Loaded event show (modal) the login-dialog and if the user did not log in react to this.

For example:

```
void FormLoad(...)
{
    var dlg = new LoginDialog();
    dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (!dlg.UserLogedIn)
    {
       // react ....
       this.Close();
    }
}
```